# Python list.index behaviour on OSX?

Tags: python, macos, list, indexing

I am studying someone else's code that was written in Python on a Mac. I am using a PC. They use list.index in cases where exceptions will be generated  (i.e: the items are missing), but they don't have exception handling. Therefore, I am trying to work out why their code ran successfully.

Does list.index generate exceptions on a Mac when items are missing, or is its behaviour different? Thanks.

I had errors upstream, my fault! Thanks guys.

Comment: No, the behavior should be the same in this case.

Comment: Check that everyone is using the same version of python, on the command-line `python -V`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide an example of the code that ran successfully on their machine, but not yours? The behavior of `list.index` shouldn't be os dependent. It should throw a ValueError if the item is not in the list (at least in Python 3.4).